# Handle specific exception from python package

Tags: python, exception, python-3.7

I would like to handle the following Exception from py_vollib/py_lets_be_rational in specific way.

```
py_lets_be_rational.exceptions.BelowIntrinsicException: The volatility is below the intrinsic value.
```

Tried this without success:

```
from py_vollib.black.implied_volatility import implied_volatility as impl_vol_b
from py_lets_be_rational.exceptions import BelowIntrinsicException

try:
    call_vol = impl_vol_b(discounted_option_price, F, K, r, t, type)
except BelowIntrinsicException as e:
    if str(e) != 'The volatility is below the intrinsic value':
        raise
    else:
        call_vol = 0
```

what am I doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/vollib/py_lets_be_rational/blob/master/py_lets_be_rational/exceptions.py#L43), you're missing the period at the end of the sentence:

```
if str(e) != 'The volatility is below the intrinsic value.':
```

I don't see the point in this check because that will always be the message the exception is created with.

Comment: oops sorry I found that out and thought I didn't actually sent the question.

Answer (score -1):

check the inputs provided by you in the formula.
you must have entered the wrong value of strike price